# How to get lagging 6 month average by ID column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to add a new column to an existing temp table named #opp_level. This new column should reflect the average spend 6 month prior to the current close date by account number.

I have tried the following 2 methods below with no luck.

> Method 1:
>
> ```
> SELECT 
> [Close Date],
> [Prior 6 Mo Date],
> [Opportunity Id],
> [Account Name],
> [Account Number],
> [Total Opportunity Amount],
> AVG([Total Opportunity Amount]) OVER (
> PARTITION BY [Account Number]
> ORDER BY [Close Date]
> RANGE BETWEEN [Prior 6 Mo Date] and [Close Date] --also tried BETWEEN 
> unbounded preceding and current row
> )
> FROM #opp_level
> ORDER BY 
> [Close Date],
> [Prior 6 Mo Date],
> [Opportunity Id],
> [Account Name],
> [Account Number],
> [Total Opportunity Amount]
> ```
>
> Method 2:
>
> ```
> select a.[Close Date],a.[Total Opportunity Amount], avg(b.[Total 
> Opportunity Amount]) AS [Prior 6 Mo Avg]
> from #opp_level a
> join #opp_level b
>   on b.[Close Date]
>      between dateadd(MONTH, -6, a.[Close Date]) and a.[Close Date]
> group by a.[Close Date], a.[Total Opportunity Amount]
> ORDER BY a.[Close Date]
> ```

My current data set looks like this without the Prior 6 Month Avg column. That is the column I would like to add in.

```
 Close Date  Prior 6 Mo Date  Opportunity Id  Account Name  Account Number  Total Opportunity Amount  Prior 6 Month Avg Opp Spend
1/1/2018      7/1/2017            12345        A Team         8763496                50                         50
6/1/2018      12/1/2017           12345        A Team         8763496                1000                     525
11/1/2018     5/1/2018            12345        A Team         8763496                500                      750
1/1/2018      7/1/2017            67890        B Team         9812081                300                      300
6/1/2018      12/1/2017           67890        B Team         9812081                2000                     1150
11/1/2018     5/1/2018            67890        B Team         9812081                80                         1040
```

Comment: have you tried AVG(CASE WHEN)?

Comment: Present your sample and expected output data in tabular format which will give better understanding.

Comment: The AVG(CASE WHEN) did not work unfortunately @Jervs

Comment: I have updated the table view, sorry about that @mkRabbani

Comment: What is the Order key to make sure which rows should come before or after which row. Your date columns current ordering misguiding to understand things.

Comment: The order doesn't really matter too much, but by date would work. I presented the data in the above format to show how the first record for the first account  will have an average of 50 since there is no data before it. While the second record of Account A will sum the before amount with the current amount (50 + 1000) since the range is within 6 months. Lastly the final row of account A will only average the last row and the second (1000 + 500) since the first record is out of range. I hope this helps clarify.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're almost there. From your first query, just replace this:

```
AVG([Total Opportunity Amount]) OVER (
PARTITION BY [Account Number]
ORDER BY [Close Date]
RANGE BETWEEN [Prior 6 Mo Date] and [Close Date] --also tried BETWEEN 
unbounded preceding and current row
```

to this:

```
AVG([Total Opportunity Amount]) OVER (
PARTITION BY [Account Number]
ORDER BY [Close Date]
ROWS BETWEEN 1 preceding and current row)
```